# Concern of Permission Check in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a Todo application which uses CQRS.
I want to check some permission for user who performs Create/Read/Update operations.

**Given**:

- I have 2 group `Office` and `Kitchen`
- Each `Todo` and `User` has to belong a group
- Each user can perform operations according the following rules

**Rules**:

- A user can read a Todo if it is in their group (Todo in Office & User in Office)
- A user can not read a Todo if it is not in their group (Todo in Office & User in Kitchen)
- A user can create a Todo in only their group (User in Office, then, Todo must be in Office)
- ...

**Table**: `Groups`

```sql
| GroupId | GroupName |
|    1    |   Office  |
|    2    |   Kitchen |
```

**Table**: `Todo`

```sql
| TodoId | GroupId |
|    1   |     1   |
|    2   |     1   |
|    3   |     2   |
```

Table: `User`

```sql
|UserId | GroupId |
|  1    |    1    |
|  2    |    1    |
|  3    |    2    |
```

**What I want to know**:

- Which layer should be responsible to check the rules above (domain, application, infrastructure)?
- Where to put this control is more suitable when we think that we are using CQRS (in controller (action), in entity, in query/command handler)?

---

Please, let me know your ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess this sort of depends on the level of complexity you want to have.
The obvious answer is, you want Commands based actions CUD to be on the command-side and the R to be on the read-side.

The layers should do what they normal do, Application co-ordinates, and the domain contains the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Application (aka Service), should co-ordinate the activities, and the Domain model should contain the rules.

Some of this may depend on the specifics, but you might do something like this...

```cs
// Todo Command Service
public ResponseModel CreateTodoItem(CreateTodoItemCommand command, User user) {
  var userPermissionCheck = _userTodoCommandPermissions.GetPermissions(user, command.GroupId);

  if (!userPermissionCheck.CanCreate) {
    return ResponseModel.Failed();
  }

  // continue

}
```

I'd do something similar on the same query-side.

In-terms of CQRS, I'm not sure there is a real need to get rid of the Service layer - but perhaps your handler is designed in a way to handle this. So it sort of depends.